# JQuery breaking on form submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a basic email sign up form which displays a bootstrap modal after the email is successfully saved. To keep it simple, I am not doing this via AJAX (i.e. I am reloading the page). The issue is that after successfully redirecting, I am getting the following error in the console:

```
readyException.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:34)
    at mightThrow (deferred.js:97)
    at process (deferred.js:139)
```

Here is the simple script it's complaining about, which is located in `index.html.erb`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#successModal').modal("show");
});
```

JQuery is definitely loading/working initially because I have another JQuery piece -- a carousel via Slick (see [jquery-slick-rails](https://github.com/bodrovis/jquery-slick-rails)) -- which works at first, but then breaks on reload. Here's the script for that, which is located in `application.js`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#carousel').slick({
        vertical: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        speed: 300
    });
});
```

One thing I have noticed is that on reload the `<head>` files are loaded in a different order. I've read elsewhere that JQuery has to be loaded before Bootstrap, so I wonder if that is part of the problem.

Here it is before:
[image]

And here it is after:
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

For now, I have added the JS to invoke the modal directly into my `index.html.erb` file. Here it is, along with a striped down version of the form:

```
<%= form_with scope: :subscriber, url: "/subscribe", method: 'post' do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control form-text" %>
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: "btn btn-lg btn-outline-success btn-styling form-text width-100"%>

    <% if params[:subscribed] %> /* Note: This gets passed back if 'subscribe' is successful' */
        <%= render "success-modal" %>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#successModal').modal("show");
            });
        </script>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Heres is the `_success_modal.html.erb` partial with which I am trying to render:

```
<div class="modal" id="successModal" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body text-center mx-auto">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
          <i class="far fa-check-circle fa-2x green"></i>
          <p class="my-3">You're on the list!</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I moved the script from my view to `application.js.erb`, but the modal is still not showing. Should I be trying to use some other logic to (a) render the partial with the modal, and (b) show the modal?

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('#carousel').slick({
        vertical: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        speed: 300
    });

    <% if params[:subscribed] %>
        <%= render "success-modal" %>
        $('#successModal').modal("show");
    <% end %>
});
```

This snippet in my `index.html.erb` view is controlled by the JQuery Slick snippet from above, and it breaks every time I redirect.

```
<div class="text-center" id="heading-text">
    <h1><b>Static header</b> of
        <span id=carousel>
            <span>Rotating header 1</span>
            <span>Rotating header 2</span>
            <span>Rotating header 3</span>
        </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Here is a slimmed version of my `Pages` controller in case it matters:

```
def subscribe
  redirect_to root_path(subscribed: :true)
end
```

**EDIT 3:**

Added a slimmed down version of the repo here: https://github.com/sp1ns1r/jquery-test.

**EDIT 4:**

After making the changes proposed by @BenTrewern, I'm now encountering the following issue:

```
Webpacker can't find application in /Users/user/thepursuit/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "entrypoints": {
    "src/style": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/src/style-cb7dd812ab53ccfcc3e1.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/src/style-cb7dd812ab53ccfcc3e1.js.map"
      ]
    }
  },
  "src/style.js": "/packs/js/src/style-cb7dd812ab53ccfcc3e1.js",
  "src/style.js.map": "/packs/js/src/style-cb7dd812ab53ccfcc3e1.js.map"
}
```

It's complaining about this in my `<head>`: `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: `modal()` is not a standard jQuery method. You need another library like Bootstrap.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in the HTML you posted.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't post the HTML because it's breaking before it even gets there. Will add.

Comment: I believe @Barmar was pointing out the fact that there is no JavaScript file named anything like "bootstrap" listed in the picture of the HTML you have included in the question. Apparently you are using some kind of framework (I've not heard of the extension erb before), so you should probably edit your question to include the tag for that framework, as the problem here seems unrelated to only jQuery.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I originally had the framework (Rails) tagged to the question, and someone removed it. Will attempt to add it back and add more details.

Comment: Looks like you are using Rails with webpacker.  If you are loading jQuery via webpack then it is only available in your included .js files and not in <script></script> tags in your views.

Comment: Also are you using Turbolinks?  Then you should be listening to $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { ... }); instead.

Comment: @BenTrewern Thanks. I'm no longer seeing the console error, but the modal still isn't loading, and the carousel is still breaking. Can you please see 'Edit 2'?

Comment: @BenTrewern Could you provide any additional guidance here?

Comment: @Mike It's at the very bottom -- `Pages`. I've stripped it down to share, but whether I have the extra logic or just the redirect, the same issue occurs.

Comment: @SpencerK. just wanted to make sure there was no funny business.  Also is this Rails 4, 5, or 6?  I feel like I've had this issue before, which was either turbo links replacing the events attached to document, or interfering with Bootstrap event handlers,.. none of those sound natural.  I just can't recall what the issue was and am hoping something will jump out in your code.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious.  It would be easier to debug if you have (1) a working version hosted somewhere (2) the full code to look at in gitlab or GitHub.  Also, perhaps in generating a stripped down version it might reveal the culprit

Comment: @Mike Rails 6. I’ll try to put something together tomorrow and share the Github link.

Comment: Just thought I'd add there is a documented Turbolinks issue with jquery-slick-rails.  See in the readme:  https://github.com/bodrovis/jquery-slick-rails.

Comment: @BenTrewern Thanks. I implemented the first proposed solution, but it doesn't seem to work :/.

Comment: OK.  When you get your copy of the code on Github / gitlab I'll have another look.

Comment: @Mike Alright I've added a slimmed down version here: https://github.com/sp1ns1r/jquery-test. Let me know if there's anything missing.

Comment: What file is in your app/javascript/packs folder.  It should be application.js.  You can't run erb through webpack.

Comment: You'll need to remove the modal code from the application.js file.  It will not work how you expect.  Webpack only compiles this code when you change your js in that pack not for each page load.

Comment: @BenTrewern OK, I'm past the first error. But now I'm back to it saying `JQuery` and `$` are not defined across slick, application.js, and bootstrap files. If you were able to get this fully functional, can you share a link to the repo?

I'm also wondering how I can get the bootstrap modal to load w/o injecting ruby into the javascript file. See what I had around Line 27 here: https://github.com/sp1ns1r/jquery-test/blob/master/app/javascript/packs/application.js.erb.

Comment: @SpencerK. I've been on break and have just returned.  I see that Ben was able to address the issue!  Glad to hear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your _head.html.erb partial you have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css' %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
```

So your slick-carousel is being loaded after your javascript pack.

You would be better off adding slick-carousel to your pack with:

```
yarn add slick-carousel
```

and require it in your application.js.erb:

```
...
require("channels")
require("slick-carousel")
```

Then you need to add your css to your pack.  What I've done to get something similar working is the following:

Add an app/javascript/packs/src/application.scss file:

```
@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick';
@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme';
```

and then import the scss file in your application.js.erb file:

```
import './src/application.scss';
```

Then remove the slick-carousel references from your _head.html.erb partial.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried a few different variations, but continue to run into this issue (see Edit 4). None of the solutions on other threads for this issue have fixed my problem.

Comment: After some work I've got this working.  See here: https://github.com/btrewern/jquery-test.  I'll update my answer when I get a minute.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I just realized that I pushed the full version of my code to that 'jquery' repo instead of the slimmed down version. Is there any way you can delete your repo so that it's not out there? I've already downloaded it.

Comment: No problem.  I've removed it now.

Comment: Great, thanks. One quick question: Do you have any idea why the styles in assets>stylesheets>application.scss.erb aren't being applied? If I add `!important` to each they seem to work, but otherwise they don't.

Comment: If !important fixes the problem then it's caused by the specificity of your selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon.  See your _head partial.  Move the "stylesheet_link_tag 'application'" below the javascript_pack_tag should fix this issue.

Comment: That did it. Thanks, again.